# accept payment form paypal without going to paypal site

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a site which have a two type of login member and provider.member request an appointment with provider and provide paypal account detail. when provider login and confirm appointment then amount has been debited (deducted) from his/her paypal account without going to paypal site. that type of payment accept I want to implement on my site .
it is possible ,if yes can you please suggest me tutorial for that.
you can suggest me for php/cakephp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful for you:

[Process Credit Cards with PayPal Payments Pro](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-process-credit-cards-with-paypal-payments-pro-using-php/)

Comment: You need paypal pro in order to make accept payments on your site without taking user to paypal.

Comment: can you please give a code example which are accepting only paypal account.

Comment: but it will accepting credit card,not the paypal account inforamtion.thanks in advanced